# Problem on the cyclic group generated by $T(z)=e^{2i\pi\theta} z$ with $\theta$ irrational.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cyclic-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, sequence-of-function

I was reading [this](https://central.bac-lac.gc.ca/.item?id=TC-OOU-20236&op=pdf&app=Library&oclc_number=1033018996) and I got stuck on a step in the proof of Theorem 1.3.18 (page 25).

In proving the implication (4) $\Rightarrow $ (5) it states:

> Since the cyclic group generated by $T$ has no element of small argument (otherwhise $T$ will have a finite order) one can construct a sequence $\{T^{a_n}
> : a_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ such that $T^{a_n} \to \mathrm{Id}$ where $n\to \infty$.

Now, I cannot see why the implication: $T$ *has* element of smallest argument  implies $T$ having finite order.

I attempt to justify the existence of such sequence $(a_n)$ by showing that $\liminf (|e^{2in\pi \theta}-1|)=0.$ But I have no clue of how this would happen.

Can you suggest me a solution please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\theta$ is irrational, there is an infinite sequence of good rational approximations to it of the form $a/q$ so that $|\theta - a/q|$ is at most $1/q^2$. This is called Dirichlet's approximation theorem. Are you familiar with it? From this it follows there's no smallest angle by looking at the angle $q\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the cyclic group $\langle T \rangle$ that is generated by $T$ has an element of smallest argument, call that argument $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$.

Let $k \ge 1$ be the least exponent such that $(k-1)\theta < 2\pi$. It follows that
$$k\theta - 2 \pi < \theta
$$
It also follows that
$$k\theta \ge 2\pi
$$
If the last inequality is strict, i.e. if $k\theta > 2 \pi$, then we have
$$0 < k\theta - 2 \pi < \theta
$$
and therefore $k\theta - 2 \pi$ is an argument of $T$ that is smaller than the smallest argument $\theta$, a contradiction.

Therefore $k\theta = 2 \pi$. Choosing $m$ such that the argument of $T^m$ is equal to $\theta$, it follows that $T^{mk}$ is the identity and so $\langle T \rangle$ is finite.